# When I click on my HTML button, a blue "selection" border is displayed

Tags: html, css, button

I created this HTML button, and after styling it with CSS, every time it's clicked a blue selection border appears around it. Is there any way to fix this? I know that the default unchanged  element does not do this when i create it, so I'm thinking it must have something to do with the CSS I added.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="drop-button" >-</button>
```

CSS:

```
.drop-button {
    background-color: #343436;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

[Here is a link to it.](http://jsfiddle.net/xytxnpyt/) http://jsfiddle.net/xytxnpyt/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Chrome. You can turn it off with this...

```
button:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: That fixed my problem, thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: Happy to help. You'll see that it doesn't do this in some other browsers. This is mainly a Chrome thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
.drop-button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn0uLqek/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Although I could not reproduce the blue selection border you are talking about in JSFiddle, try adding "outline-width:0px;" to the button's CSS and see if that does anything